# A single set of moves $S$ that, if repeated, solves the Rubik's cube from any state

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, alternative-proof, rubiks-cube

**I am looking for a proof verification. I often find these concepts simple, but struggle to communicate them clearly. Communication in mathematics is very important to me:**
Examples could be:

- Any mistakes or vagueness.
- Comments to make my arguments shorter.
- An alternative proof or reference to an alternative proof, I could not find this problem anywhere.

I want to prove that it is **not** possible to have a Rubik's cube in an arbitrary state for which there exists a set of moves $S$ that solves the Cube.

The restriction here is that we first look at a cube, if it's not solved, we close our eyes and **apply** that set of moves, look at it again, if it's not solved, repeat the same moves. We do this over and over again. Sure there is a very very long sequence of moves that goes through all possible configurations, but you might skip a solved cube if you have your eyes closed.

> No single set of moves $S$ exist, such that is solves the cube from any given configuration.

We will show that there exists no set of moves $S$ that can solve the cube from any given starting position. We will argue by contradiction. Suppose it is possible to solve **any** state by repeating a certain set of moves. the moves then must cycle through every possible configuration, as every single configuration must lead to a solved cube, at some point. We then know that the Rubik's cube is cyclic and it has the single generator, namely  this set of moves called $S$.

**Lemma: Any cyclic group is Abelian**

First observe that any element in a cyclic group can be represented in terms of the cycle generator $c$, so for $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ we know that some arbitrary elements in this cyclic group are given by $x=c^a$ and $y = c^b$.
Now notice that for any cyclic group we have that the generator $c$ satisfies $$xy=c^a c^b= c^{a+b}=c^{b+a}=c^b c^a=yx$$ because addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ is commutative, it is a ring after all.
 This means that if the group is cyclic it must also be Abelian, which it clearly isn't, we use $r^2 g^2 r^2 $ versus $r^2 r^2 g^2 $ as a counterexample. We reach a contradiction, hence no such set of moves $S$ exists. $\square$

Comment: So what exactly is your question? The proof looks fine to me. Is it <proof-verification>?

Comment: added the tag* my bad

Comment: proof also lgtm

Comment: One might note that $c^{a+b} = c^{b+a}$ isn't so much about $\mathbb Z$, but more the associativity of the group. You have $c^{a+b} = \underbrace{c\cdot \ldots\cdot c}_{a+b \text{ times}} = \underbrace{c\cdot\ldots\cdot c}_{b \text{ times}} \cdot \underbrace{c\cdot\ldots\cdot c}_{a\text{ times}} = c^b \cdot c^a$. This *implies* that the cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/_n$ or $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh yeah, now that you say so.

Comment: Very nice observation

Comment: Lol wesley nice huiswerk voor adm